# How to display a percific table from sqlserver into a datagridview using combobox in winform

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview, combobox

so i got a small homework from my teacher during this whole corona thing

First: create a database in SQL with 6 table , lets call it A, B, C, D, E and F

Then: Using VisualStudio to

-Create an MDI form and 3 childs (also call childform into MDI form w/o duplicate) (done)

-In the 1st childform: Display table A into a datagridview and sort the data in that table using a combobox (done)

and the next one is where im stuck at

-In the 2nd childform: create a combobox and a datagridview. Combobox will display (and let you choose) the table in the SQL, and the datagridview will display that percific table.

that is to say: if i select A from the combobox, then the content of table A will be display into the datagridview, B then content of B will be display into the datagridview, and so on.

and if something doesnt make sense to you ... it might be cause english isnt my first language.
and thanks for your help in advance

*edit*

what i have done so far: 
so the combobox, i manually inserted the table name
then in the -lets call it childform2- childform2_load section.i tried the following (multiple times with diff idea in mind) (also just picked up c# a while back so expect dumb idea)

-using dataadapter to "select * from" + combobox.text > doesnt work

-using if to make independant case of childform2_load (each with diff "select * from correspondingtable*) > doesnt seem to work .... (if combobox.text = "A" then ........ *select * from A)

and .. thats all i've manage to do so far.The problem im encountering is:

so the select part .... how would one select the table acording to the combobox's selection ... like ..... if i select A from the combobox then the select command in the "select * from x" . that X would register as A, and register B if i select B. I tried "select * from " + combobox.text and that obviously wouldnt work since the whole select thing must be put in " ". and making diff case of formload using if doesnt work and i think i know why it will never work so ... yeah .....im stuck

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking for *homework help* must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) You can find more information on how to ask a homework question in the FAQ: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/2029983)

Comment: You've added a description of what you've done, but you haven't told us what the difficulty you're having is. Have a look at the FAQ link I've given you, which explains how to ask.

Comment: The select statement is a string.  So you need to change the table name in the string.  You can use : string commandText = string.Format("select * from {0}", tablename);